# What do main characters survive on during the zombie apocalypse?

Tags: plot-explanation, zombieland

I love Zombieland. I happened to watch it last week on FX a couple of times in a row, and I was thinking after the movie that it never really showed us about their eating habits and how they survive during the zombie apocalypse. We know Harrelson's character was obsessed with Twinkies, but he didn't find one until the end, and there was this truck with snowballs in the movie. There was no reference further in the movie if they were surviving on that.

What do all the main characters eat during the course of the movie?

Judging from the timeline in the movie I wonder if all the grocery stores in towns stopped carrying fresh food after the mutation struck? Anyone have any interesting answers to my question?

Comment: Snowballs, of course.  This is why Tallahassee was always so angry.

Comment: It had to be that. :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If snowballs and Twinkies still survive, then I would presume that there was also plenty of tinned and dried food to be found in shops and warehouses. I'm also fairly sure that, despite the zombies, there was plenty of electricity (the movie doesn't make clear whether this is from local generators or from the grid, but there is *clearly* electricity in many scenes including the theme park at the end) so frozen food will still be available.

It is not a serious movie and it would probably be petty to point out the inconsistency of the existence of network power in a world dominated by zombies where nobody is running the power plants or maintaining the grid. It certainly didn't detract from my enjoyment of the movie.

Comment: Though unlikely to keep working without maintenance, they do actually mention where power comes from in the recently-released sequel, _Zombieland Double Tap_: "As long as it keeps raining, the hydros will keep providing power" or something to that effect, referring to dams and hydroelectric power plants.

Answer (score 7):

Also, I think in Zombieland the zombie apocalypse is only supposed to have happened about 2 months ago, so there would be a lot of food that would still be fresh.  From the comment above if fridges were still on then I reckon there would be loads of edible food.